# Change zsh completion to put completions above the prompt

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm a long-time tcsh user that finally decided to try out zsh. I've been toying around with completion, but one thing I don't like is that when I hit tab for a completion that might have a lot of values, it prints the completion options below the prompt, pushing the prompt up off the bottom of the terminal. TCSH would leave the old prompt, print the completions on new lines below, and then reprint the prompt and the command that you had typed so far.

Is there any way to change the completion logic so that completion options are printed above the prompt?

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I vaguely remember having thought the same thought in 1993 or so. I can attest to the fact that you get used to the Bash behavior, but out of curiosity, I'd like to see a solution, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unsetopt ALWAYS_LAST_PROMPT` will give you the effect but may affect certain menu completion settings.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!